# Adding ArcGIS JSAPI code to Existing Angular app?

Tags: angular, arcgis-js-api

I am new to web dev. coding. I managed to scrape together some code for a simple web GIS app. using ArcGIS Javascript API version 3.xx. The ArcGIS JSAPI app has some simple functionality like a click event that return some value back from the layers. There is an existing Angular(version 7) app running in our environment that I inherited from my other colleagues, with different modules inside of the src-->app folder already.

Can I just simply create another module inside the src-->app folder of the Angular app, maybe called it "gis-map", and copy and paste the html/js code from the ArcGIS JSAPI app into the gis-map.component.html, " ".ts, " ".css?

Will this approach work?

And could I expand that later on, to add a Angular click event on the map layers and get back the result?

Comment: There are some resources in this [gitub repo](https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/frameworks/angular) that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  I did take a quick look at the repo, and I will most likely try to follow one of those examples.  It looks like those are all starting fresh Angular project.  What about adding on to a existing Angular project?  Maybe do an npm install on just the Esri ArcGIS modules/library, then creating additional component on top of that?

Comment: To be honest I am not an angular user so I can't help with specifics on that. I'm also much more familiar with the version 4.x ArcGIS Javascript API. [This page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/using-frameworks/) from the 4.x documentation talks about integrating into a framework like angular. The main thing is loading the esri modules for your map, you can't just npm install the API because it is built around using Dojo AMD for loading modules. However, they have a library called [esri-loader](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader) to get around this if your not using Dojo